# smooth out jagged geom_segment to look like geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to put a reference line in a plot via `geom_segment`.

A simplified example:

```
tryCatch({
spaghetti_smooth_ref = qplot(age,T_self, data=sest,geom="blank") + 
    geom_smooth(method='lm',alpha=0.1, colour = "black") + 
    geom_segment(aes(x = 16, xend = 45,y = coef(us_ref)["(Intercept)"], yend = coef(us_ref)["(Intercept)"] + coef(us_ref)["age"] * 45), linetype = "solid", colour = "#5e8fb0", alpha = 0.5, size = 0.1) + 
    facet_wrap(~ country)+
    scale_linetype_discrete()
}, error = function(e){warning(e)})
```

As you can see below, `geom_smooth()` is rendered a lot more smoothly than `geom_segment()`.

How can I improve on this? It's the same when viewed in Rstudio on Mac and when rendered as PDF. I've also plotted the exact same slope once using the raw data and `geom_smooth()` and once using `geom_segment()`, they still differ.

[image: jagged segment]

Comment: `annotate('segment')` works. [See posting here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47971820/irregular-appearance-of-segments-ggplot2).

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is 5 years old, I ran into the same issues recently and was able to resolve it. Hopefully my answer can help others experiencing something similar.

You can create an additional data frame containing the min and max values of the x and y-axis. Then use `geom_line()` to add the desired line.

```
data_df = data.frame(Gender = rep(c("Female", "Male"),each = 10),
                     Height = c(63.26153, 61.56266, 64.80651, 63.29383, 66.44624, 67.12988, 64.13034, 66.64640, 64.74866, 73.08489, 
                                62.01556, 72.80084, 69.28989, 67.56494, 68.01175, 70.99855, 68.19854, 71.81611, 73.08489, 70.95103),
                     Weight = c(126.4268, 131.7959, 156.0956, 159.8213, 135.6089, 146.6043, 121.2926, 156.4250, 133.5414, 158.2851,
                                117.6670, 206.8282, 179.5619, 156.1813, 175.0151, 195.9590, 176.4568, 205.9251, 230.6788, 196.6997))

model = lm(Weight~Height, data = data_df)

lines_df = data.frame(Height = c(min(data_df$Height), max(data_df$Height)),
                      Weight = c(coef(model)["(Intercept)"] + coef(model)["Height"] * min(data_df$Height),
                                 coef(model)["(Intercept)"] + coef(model)["Height"] * max(data_df$Height)))

ggplot(data_df, aes(x = Height, y = Weight)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", alpha = 0.1, colour = "black", size = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Weight), data = lines_df, linetype = "solid", colour = "#5e8fb0", size = 0.5)+
  facet_grid(.~Gender)
```

[image: PDF of linear models]

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just define your own reference line with `abline`? E.g.

```
+ geom_abline(intercept = 48.5, slope = 0.1)
```

Comment: Yes, but abline goes beyond the data range and would hence look odd compared to the smooths.