# Irregular appearance of segments (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, lines, segment

I am doing a plot using ggplot2. Everything goes well until I put the lines of the models (PGLS). When I try to put them using geom_segment() the aspect of the lines is not smooth, is like they were made of several short horizontal lines.

I don't know why that is happening and I tried to look for help online with no results.

```
p3 <- ggplot(data =biases, aes(y=prevbias, x=bsbias, color=parasitism))+ 
geom_point(size=2)+
xlab("sexual size dimorphism") + ylab("bias in blood parasite prevalence")+
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0),color="grey50", linetype="dashed")+ 
geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0),color="grey50",linetype="dashed")+
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=12),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=12))+
scale_color_manual(values=c("darkred","grey15"))+
geom_segment(aes(x = -0.659, xend = 0.6325, y = -0.0065069, yend =-0.0065069 + 0.0162262*0.6325), color="darkred")+
geom_segment(aes(x = -0.33910, xend = 0.75890, y = 0.0055704, yend = 0.0055704 + 0.0644188*0.75890), color="grey15")
print(p3)
```

[image: here is the plot and the two lines]

Comment: you want `annotate('segment')` or `inherit.aes=FALSE`, otherwise the segments are drawn multiple times because the layer inherits from the overall `biases` dataset (and the renderer/aliasing gets confused producing this jagged mess).

Comment: Many thanks, that solved the problem!